# What's the difference between class reference and class object when the function return class object in C++?

Tags: c++

In order to make my question clear, I give the following example:

```
  #include <iostream>   


   class Abc
    {
       public:
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
     };
     class Abc  fun1()
      {
         Abc obj;
         obj.a = 3;
         obj.b = 4;
         obj.c = 5;
          return obj;

        };

       int main ()
       {
          Abc obj1;
          obj1 = fun1();
          std::cout<<"obj1 address is "<<&obj1<<std::endl;

          Abc &obj11 = fun1();
          std::cout<<"obj11 address is "<<&obj11<<std::endl;



         return 0;
 }
```

As you can see the function's return value is a class object, and when you invoke this function to create the class object, you can either use the class object `obj1` or class reference `obj11`. For me they are the same, and I was wondering what's the difference between them and which practice is encouraged.

**EDIT:**
  It can compile on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I think you're missing a `const` on the reference declaration.

Comment: its not compiling.http://ideone.com/QSrlb1

Comment: @Columbo: Shouldn't, but does on one popular compiler.

Comment: `Abc &obj11 = fun1();` might compile on some compilers (MSVC allows binding temporaries to non-`const` references, though it will issue a warning when you do), but technically it's not allowed by the C++ specification, so this program is ill-formed.

Comment: @Columbo Now it can with VC 2010

Comment: @feelfree That doesn't make it good practice to do so, and it makes your code non-portable. (It isn't guaranteed to compile correctly on any other C++ compiler.) There is a good reason this isn't allowed by the C++ specification. MSVC is known for helping programmers to aim the gun at their feet before pulling the trigger.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks, and I feel curious that it can compile on vc 2010

Comment: @feelfree MSVC allows a lot of things that the C++ specification forbids, as "extensions" to the C++ language. It should emit a warning when you use such an extension, if you have warnings turned all the way up (which you should always do!). You would be well served to avoid using these extensions as they will result in non-portable code that likely doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @cdhowie, `+1` on both of your comments. Neither g++ nor clang++ compiles the OP's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Abc &obj11 = fun1();
```

**This line makes the program ill-formed;** the C++ specification forbids temporaries to be bound to a reference that is not `const`.  A compliant C++ compiler would emit an error to this effect.  Presumably you are using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, which is well-known for allowing the binding of a temporary to a non-`const` reference in contradiction to the C++ specification.

```
const Abc &obj11 = fun1();
```

This line would be well-formed, and it causes the temporary to be bound to the reference.

In any case, when binding a temporary to a reference the temporary will have its lifetime extended to match the lifetime of the reference, so when the reference goes out of scope the temporary will also be destroyed.  In other words, in terms of lifetime semantics it's equivalent to the line `Abc obj1 = fun1();`<sup>1</sup>. If you are using a compiler that elides copies then all copies will be elided in both cases. If not eliding copies then the reference case will involve one less copy:

- Value case, the returned object will be copied into a temporary and then destroyed, and the temporary will be copied into `obj1` and then destroyed.
- Reference case, the returned object will be copied into a temporary and then destroyed, and the temporary will be bound to the reference.

Note that a decent optimizing compiler will optimize away all copies as well as the reference detail completely, leaving you with identical assembly output for both of the cases in your question.

(If you're interested, [here is a test case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c638216301b12c0) with code slightly tweaked from that in your question. Note that no copies are made in either case unless copy elision is disabled.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is different from the code `Abc obj1; obj1 = fun1();` in your question. I intentionally changed it, because the code you have written isn't directly comparable and so it doesn't make much sense to compare them.  If you rewrite it as `Abc obj1 = fun1();` then the two lines can be compared, because `Abc obj1; obj1 = fun1();` involves default-construction and then copy-assignment.

Comment: *Note that a decent optimizing compiler...* FWIW, `Abc obj1; obj1 = fun1();` still causes the constructor to be called twice (checked with g++ and clang++), whereas `const Abc &obj11 = fun1();` only once

Comment: @InnocentBystander Yeah, I just discovered that myself and am editing.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I'm curious if you explicitly disabled copy elision though, because at `-O2` I don't see any copies at all.

Comment: cdhowie, I haven't. But -O2 doesn't seem to make any diff. I still get 2 ctor calls. clang 3.5.0, gcc 4.8.3

Comment: @InnocentBystander That's very odd. Check the link in my answer, there g++ is definitely eliding all copies with `-O2` and I only see one default ctor call in both cases, and no copy ctor calls at all.

Comment: @InnocentBystander you use default-construction and assignment operator in your code above in comment. That is not same as initialization.

Comment: now if I change `Abc obj1; obj1 = fun1();` to simply `Abc obj1 = fun1();` as in your linked example, then the elision works. which all makes sense.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Good catch. Yeah, that is one of the lines I changed because without changing it the two cases aren't even comparable anyway. I will note that in my answer.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, yes, that's right, as this is what the OP example did. I think we are all good -- my comment was in regards to cdhowie's original answer :)

Answer (score 1):

they are not the same. 
in the line

```
obj1 = fun1();
```

fun1() creates an objects , then obj1 *COPIES* the content of it . so you have two objects, one , anonymous , that you can't use anymore , and obj1 , which is an exact copy of it.

in the line

```
Abc &obj11 = fun1();
```

you catch the object fun1() created which a reference. now you have only *ONE* object , caught with a reference.

notice that `A a` and `A& a = b` are not the same . `A a`  creates an object on the stack . `A& a = b` does not create another object , it just "catches" one with a reference.

Comment: *"A& a = b does not create another object"* -- Actually it depends on whether you're eliding copies. If you're not eliding copies then it will still make a copy; the returned object will be copied into a temporary, and the temporary is what gets bound to the reference. (And it still won't compile on a compliant C++ compiler...)